# How to set position of a newly created div upon a drop?

Tags: jquery

In my drop handler I create a DOM node **newNode**. I want **newNode** to itself be draggable, and located initially where the current drop occurred in *#container*, with **newNode** parented in *#container*. The code below does not give newNode the correct initial location, although I can drag it around. Any ideas?

```
drop: function(event, ui) { 
    newNode = $("<div>new node</div>")[0]
    $("#container).append(newNode)
    $(newNode).draggable({  helper: "original" })

    newNode.style.position = 'absolute'
    newNode.style.left = ui.helper.left
    newNode.style.top = ui.helper.top
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try adding the style before appending it. also you're missing a `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop: function(event, ui) { 
    newNode = $("<div>new node</div>")[0].css({position:'absolute', left:ui.helper.left, top:ui.helper.top}).draggable({  helper: "original" });
    $("#container").append(newNode)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop: function(event, ui) { 
    newNode = $("<div>new node</div>")[0]
    $("#container").append(newNode)
    $(newNode).draggable({  helper: "original" })

    newNode.style.position = 'absolute'
    newNode.style.left = ui.helper.left
    newNode.style.top = ui.helper.top
}
```

**you forgot "**

and you can add new class in newNode

```
newNode.addClass("classe");
```

and manipule css by class

```
$(".classe").attr("style", <yourcss>);
```